# Javascript Variables Not Globally Returning / Adding Together

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add both Facebook and Twitter share counters together, however all my efforts have failed.

```
<script>
        tweets = 0;
        function getTwitterCount(url){
            $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?',             function(data){
            tweets = data.count;
            $('#twitterCount').html(tweets);
            return true;
        });
     }
     var urlBase='http://abcdfav4.com/About/KickStarterCampaign/Rewards/ThePeaceSensation.html';
     getTwitterCount(urlBase);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/http://abcdfav4.com/About/KickStarterCampaign/Rewards/ThePeaceSensation.html',
        success: function(data) {
            showCount(data);
        }
    });
    var fbshares = 0;
    function showCount(responseText) {

        // Save the parsed JSON
        var json = responseText;

        // Check if the response contains a 'shares' property
        // If it doesn't, we can just exit this function
        if (!json.hasOwnProperty('shares'))
            return;

        // A shares property and value must exist, update
        // the span element with the share count
        fbshares = json.shares;
        $('#fb-share-count').html(fbshares);
    }

    var TotalShares = tweets + fbshares;
    $('#total-share-count').html(TotalShares);
</script>
```

I could really do with some outside insight as I've been working crazy to get this website up and running ASAP and I'm probably overlooking the most obvious of things...

**Console Log Reads:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fbshares is not defined
sdk.js:64 Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
card.html?v=2:79 Uncaught ReferenceError: I18n is not defined
sdk.js:64 FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
```

However despite this message, the Facebook and Twitter counters are working 100%, I just cannot get them to add together.

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: @minitech Nothing, I cannot seem to return the variable outside of the function, I have tried testing with alerts and whatnot but zilch!

Comment: Are you able to log the number of tweets and facebook shares within each corresponding AJAX request?

Comment: You are fetching tweet and share counts asynchronously, which means that they are inserted as text before their values are updated by whatever data that is returned by either of your AJAX calls. You should look at promises :)

Comment: The Facebook and Twitter shares do show on the page like they should, the problem I am facing is adding them together

Comment: Does anything appear in the console? Are the responses in your browser’s network panel what you expect?

Comment: So I should fetch the numbers from the HTML to set the total shares @Terry ?

Comment: No. When making either Ajax calls to Facebook or Twitter, assign the returned promises as a variable. Use `$.when()` to check that both promises have been resolved, and then update the count and perform the DOM insertion.

Comment: Editing now with console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
var tweets;

function getTwitterCount(url) {
  $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    tweets = data.count;
    $('#twitterCount').html(tweets);

    showTotal();
  });
}
var urlBase = 'http://abcdfav4.com/About/KickStarterCampaign/Rewards/ThePeaceSensation.html';
getTwitterCount(urlBase);

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/http://abcdfav4.com/About/KickStarterCampaign/Rewards/ThePeaceSensation.html',
  success: showCount
});

var fbshares;

function showCount(responseText) {

  // Save the parsed JSON
  var json = responseText;

  // Check if the response contains a 'shares' property
  // If it doesn't, we can just exit this function
  if (!json.hasOwnProperty('shares'))
    return;

  // A shares property and value must exist, update
  // the span element with the share count
  fbshares = json.shares;
  $('#fb-share-count').html(fbshares);

  showTotal();
}

function showTotal() {
    if (tweets !== undefined && fbshares !== undefined)
        $('#total-share-count').html(tweets + fbshares);
}
```

Basically `showTotal` attempts to sum the two values after each callback. When both values are defined, it will place the sum into the HTML.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you very much :) (Will award as answer in 3 minutes)

Comment: Just to note, I've recently found out that `$.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?` is not a supported / available API endpoint, so even if this worked for a while, the chances are that your IP and script would be blocked before long.